# How to plan convoluted measurements

Tags: numerics, convolution

I have a physical function $f(x)$ which I intend to measure. Problem is that I cannot read it directly, but through a response function $g(x)$ which is known to me with great accuracy and any one measurement is actually a convolution $M(y) = \int f(x)g(y-x)dx$. What is known about $f(x)$ is that its sharply peaked around some known value $x_0$, its symmetric around it and falls off to zero quite fast away from $x_0$. I do not know exact shape nor any other relevant descriptors (peak value, FWHM, momenta, etc).

I have a limited time to measure, which means - limited number of points. Given that I don't know much about $f(x)$, is it possible to determine beforehand a set of measuring points $x_0 , x_1, x_2,...$  so I can reliably do the numerical deconvolution later? Or, if the deconvolution is sensitive to - let say FWHM, is there any "strategy" that I can correct my measuring points sequence on-the-fly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is an "inverse problem": You are trying to recover something (in your case, the function $f(x)$) from indirect and potentially noisy measurements (namely, the convolved data). The question of how to choose your measurement points then becomes a problem in "optimal experimental design".

There is a substantial amount of literature on optimal experimental design, both for the case of designing a measurement strategy a priori, and in response to already measured values.

Comment: Thank you, inverse problem OED seems right terminology to pursue.

Answer (score 2):

you say you don't know the exact shape of f(x) but then you describe it as a Gaussian. Is f(x) LTI? If so, why not make many measurements and estimate the critical parameters which describe a Gaussian, then average those parameters?

Comment: It is not Gaussian, for example Lorentzian also fits my description - that is what I mean when I said "I do not know exact shape [of the function f(x)]". Also, like I said, I have limited time available which translates into limited number of points, so I have one attempt and have to get it right.